# Android app crashes unexpectedly on emulator

Tags: android, crash

here is my error log please help?

I am a newbie to android and this is my first app

```
package gaurav.rapp.swamiji;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class BeWithSwamijiActivity extends Activity implements ViewFactory {
    Integer pics[]={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10,R.drawable.img11,R.drawable.img12,R.drawable.img13,R.drawable.img14,R.drawable.img15,R.drawable.img16,R.drawable.img17};
    ImageSwitcher iSwitcher;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);
        iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.fade_in));
        iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
            }
        });


    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c; 
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
            iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            return iView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView iView=new ImageView(this);
        iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        iView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        return iView;
    }
}
```

Log

```
05-13 21:58:39.107: I/Process(397): Sending signal. PID: 397 SIG: 9
05-13 21:58:45.517: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 4% free 6362K/6595K, paused 75ms
05-13 21:58:45.587: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.624MB for 4566704-byte allocation
05-13 21:58:45.697: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 10820K/11079K, paused 86ms
05-13 21:58:45.887: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10820K/11079K, paused 25ms+3ms
05-13 21:58:46.427: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10820K/11079K, paused 112ms
05-13 21:58:46.547: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.362MB for 8114772-byte allocation
05-13 21:58:46.839: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 18745K/19015K, paused 72ms
05-13 21:58:47.057: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 18745K/19015K, paused 4ms+16ms
05-13 21:58:47.680: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5051K, 26% free 15340K/20679K, paused 72ms
05-13 21:58:47.889: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 21% free 16537K/20679K, paused 71ms
05-13 21:58:47.889: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.284MB for 2179600-byte allocation
05-13 21:58:48.037: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 18666K/20679K, paused 75ms
05-13 21:58:48.307: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 18666K/20679K, paused 5ms+3ms
05-13 21:58:48.511: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1197K, 11% free 18425K/20679K, paused 73ms
05-13 21:58:48.530: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.705MB for 1735988-byte allocation
05-13 21:58:48.681: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 20120K/22407K, paused 76ms
05-13 21:59:09.187: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 961K, 13% free 19660K/22407K, paused 75ms
05-13 21:59:11.737: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 678K, 10% free 20385K/22407K, paused 143ms
05-13 21:59:11.797: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.518MB for 4776976-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:11.971: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 25049K/27079K, paused 85ms
05-13 21:59:12.117: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 25049K/27079K, paused 4ms+3ms
05-13 21:59:12.327: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 25049K/27079K, paused 93ms
05-13 21:59:12.437: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.619MB for 8494048-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:12.589: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 33344K/35399K, paused 82ms
05-13 21:59:12.877: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 33345K/35399K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-13 21:59:29.208: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4862K, 17% free 29383K/35399K, paused 84ms
05-13 21:59:31.130: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 353K, 13% free 30855K/35399K, paused 84ms
05-13 21:59:31.137: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.266MB for 2179600-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:31.287: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 32983K/35399K, paused 82ms
05-13 21:59:31.538: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 32983K/35399K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-13 21:59:31.647: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1549K, 12% free 31435K/35399K, paused 92ms
05-13 21:59:31.692: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 33.028MB for 2384216-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:31.880: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 33764K/37767K, paused 100ms
05-13 21:59:32.057: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 33764K/37767K, paused 4ms+4ms
05-13 21:59:32.307: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 33764K/37767K, paused 108ms
05-13 21:59:32.377: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.073MB for 4241380-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:32.547: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 37906K/41927K, paused 97ms
05-13 21:59:32.797: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 37906K/41927K, paused 4ms+14ms
05-13 21:59:34.747: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2329K, 13% free 36533K/41927K, paused 98ms
05-13 21:59:35.037: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1304K, 12% free 37261K/41927K, paused 4ms+4ms
05-13 21:59:42.547: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 337K, 11% free 37524K/41927K, paused 88ms
05-13 21:59:42.607: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Grow heap (frag case) to 41.255MB for 4776976-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:42.801: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 42188K/46599K, paused 104ms
05-13 21:59:43.021: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 42188K/46599K, paused 4ms+4ms
05-13 21:59:43.180: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 42189K/46599K, paused 98ms
05-13 21:59:43.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(409): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8494048-byte allocation
05-13 21:59:43.327: D/dalvikvm(409): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 8K, 10% free 42180K/46599K, paused 143ms
05-13 21:59:43.327: E/dalvikvm-heap(409): Out of memory on a 8494048-byte allocation.
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001b5c8 self=0x125d8
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   | sysTid=409 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1342913432
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   | schedstat=( 10690152881 5424008534 597 ) utm=864 stm=205 core=0
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
05-13 21:59:43.337: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
05-13 21:59:43.347: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
05-13 21:59:43.347: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
05-13 21:59:43.347: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
05-13 21:59:43.347: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
05-13 21:59:43.347: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:655)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:510)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:289)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.ImageSwitcher.setImageResource(ImageSwitcher.java:41)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at gaurav.rapp.swamiji.BeWithSwamijiActivity$1.onItemClick(BeWithSwamijiActivity.java:39)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:867)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:557)
05-13 21:59:43.357: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:842)
05-13 21:59:43.377: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4609)
05-13 21:59:43.377: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
05-13 21:59:43.377: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
05-13 21:59:43.377: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.387: I/dalvikvm(409):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
05-13 21:59:43.407: I/dalvikvm(409):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1264)
05-13 21:59:43.407: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2315)
05-13 21:59:43.407: I/dalvikvm(409):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4677)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2392)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2054)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-13 21:59:43.417: I/dalvikvm(409):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:43.417: D/AndroidRuntime(409): Shutting down VM
05-13 21:59:43.417: W/dalvikvm(409): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:655)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:510)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:289)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.ImageSwitcher.setImageResource(ImageSwitcher.java:41)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at gaurav.rapp.swamiji.BeWithSwamijiActivity$1.onItemClick(BeWithSwamijiActivity.java:39)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:867)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:557)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:842)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4609)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1264)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2315)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4677)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2392)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2054)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-13 21:59:43.467: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 21:59:46.117: I/Process(409): Sending signal. PID: 409 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you place Activity code here

Answer (score 0):

> Out of memory on a 8494048-byte allocation.

Don't try to load 8MB bitmaps! Resize your assets to something more appropriate, or look at BitmapFactory.Options to downscale whatever it is you are trying to load.

Comment: yeah its sort of an image gallary I am using jpg formatfor images

Comment: Also I will be really greatful if you can check my code for memory leaks an let me know the improvement

Comment: Actually its runtime exception and its main caused due to memory consumed at runtime by code. Solution would be the code or device fragmentation(it always depend upon the device) or also the resources you are using in executable. Please check above mentioned point than only you can solve the out of memory issue.